# JQuery Portfolio with Dynamic Data from a DB in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, portfolio, aspnetdb

I want to create a portfolio page like the one in the link below but I am trying to get all the information (Categories and Images and names etc) from a LinqDataSource.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-jquery/

I am having the same html page source with the one in the sample in the link but It doesnt work in the asp.net file ?

Any explanation for that ?

Thx in advance

K

Comment: <asp:Repeater ID="projectRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource2">
<HeaderTemplate>
 <ul id="portfolio">
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
    <li class="<%#Eval("SubCategory.Name") %>"><a href="#"><img src="Account/Files/<%#Eval("ImageFile") %>" alt="" height="100" width="100" /><%#Eval("Name") %></a></li>
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
 </ul>
</FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>

trying to do sthg like this !

Comment: we'll have to see the source for your page.

Comment: Well, when I click on a filter, it doesn't filter that and focus on that filter.

Comment: the page source is exactly the same with the one in the sample except for the filters. I have only one filter for one item so one class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the demo each li has multiple classes that are used to specify their categories, your code only looks like each thing can be in one category.

The actual rendered page would be something to look at.

You should put this line

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

above the jquery you have on the page, also, i see two of your class names are "MY SQL" and "ASP.NET" those wont work because one has a space in it and the other has a "." in it.

Comment: yes there are multiple classes for each tag those classes are filters and in my case I want to filter only with one tag which is the subcategory of that item. That's the only difference, any idea how to fix that ?